# Vuetify How can I sort a custom cell in a v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table with these headers:

```js
    headersfav: [
      {text: 'Datum', value: 'createdate'},
      {text: 'Nachname', value: 'lastname'},
      {text: 'Vorname', value: 'firstname'},
      {text: 'Adresse', value: 'address', sortable: true},
      {text: 'Status', value: 'status'},
    ],
```

I use it in a v-data-table component like this:

```js
<v-data-table
    :headers="headersfav"
    :items="itemsfav"
    :search="searchfav"
    :custom-filter="customSearch"
    :sort-by="['createdate']"
    multi-sort
    :sort-desc="[true]"
>
```

For the address field, I use this:

```
<template #item.address="{ item }">{{ item.street }}, {{ item.city }}</template>
```

When I tried to sort it, nothing happens, must I use here a custom-sort function? And how can I make it?

Comment: Is the `address` field a primitive or an object/array?

Comment: You can see it in my question: `<template #item.address="{ item }">{{ item.street }}, {{ item.city }}</template>`

Answer (score 1):

Since the property `address` seems to be an object, you have to point to the actual property upon it needs to be sorted, this is done in the header definitions in the `value` property:

In this case it could be by `address.street` or `address.city`

```
    headersfav: [
      {text: 'Datum', value: 'createdate'},
      {text: 'Nachname', value: 'lastname'},
      {text: 'Vorname', value: 'firstname'},
      {text: 'Adresse', value: 'address.street', sortable: true},
      {text: 'Status', value: 'status'},
    ],
```